# Local Storage not loading upon return visit?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a browser game but I've run into a issue I cant fix no matter how hard I try.

Click the green square increases the counter

and console shows variable being saved to `localStorage`

but upon returning on the website it returns to 0

Below is my entire JS file. Only part that matters is at the bottom and you can go see for yourself at https://sleepyshepherd.com

```js
//Saved Variables
let ashCount = 0;
let firetruck = 0;

//Initialize Game
window.onload = function() {
  const realmTab = document.createElement("div");
  const settingsTab = document.createElement("div");
  const shopTab = document.createElement("div");
  const statsTab = document.createElement("div");
  const upgradesTab = document.createElement("div");
  const burningBtn = document.createElement("div");
  const enslavedTab = document.createElement("div");
  const e1 = document.createElement("div");

  realmTab.id = "realm";
  upgradesTab.id = "upgrades";
  settingsTab.id = "settings";
  shopTab.id = "shop";
  statsTab.id = "stats";
  enslavedTab.id = "enslaved";
  burningBtn.id = "burning";
  e1.id = "e1";

  const t1 = document.createTextNode("Realm");
  realmTab.appendChild(t1); 
  const t2 = document.createTextNode("Upgrades");
  upgradesTab.appendChild(t2); 
  const t3 = document.createTextNode("Shop");
  shopTab.appendChild(t3); 
  const t4 = document.createTextNode("Stats");
  statsTab.appendChild(t4); 
  const t5 = document.createTextNode("Settings");
  settingsTab.appendChild(t5); 

  document.getElementById("menu").appendChild(realmTab);
  document.getElementById("menu").appendChild(upgradesTab);
  document.getElementById("menu").appendChild(shopTab);
  document.getElementById("menu").appendChild(statsTab);
  document.getElementById("menu").appendChild(settingsTab);
  document.getElementById("destroy").appendChild(burningBtn);
  document.getElementById("destroy").appendChild(enslavedTab);
  document.getElementById("enslaved").appendChild(e1);

  //Menu Buttons
  const viewport1 = document.querySelector(".viewport");

  //Realm View Select
  document.querySelector("#realm").addEventListener("click",  function() {
    viewport1.id = "realmView";
  });

  //Upgrades View Select
  document.querySelector("#upgrades").addEventListener("click",  function() {
    viewport1.id = "upgradeView";
  });

  //shop View Select
  document.querySelector("#shop").addEventListener("click",  function() {
    viewport1.id = "shopView";
  });

  //stats View Select
  document.querySelector("#stats").addEventListener("click",  function() {
    viewport1.id = "statsView";
  });

  //settings View Select
  document.querySelector("#settings").addEventListener("click",  function() {
    viewport1.id = "settingsView";
  });

  // Destroy 
  function increaseAsh() {
    ashCount += 1;
  }

  document.querySelector("#destroy").addEventListener("click", increaseAsh);

  //Resources
  const r1 = document.createElement("div");
  r1.id = "r1";
  document.querySelector("#resources").appendChild(r1);

  const t6 = document.createElement("p");
  r1.appendChild(t6);

  window.setInterval(function() {
    t6.textContent = ashCount;
  }, 16);

  //load game
  let sg = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("save"));
  sg.ashCount = ashCount;
}

// Save Game Interval
window.setInterval(function() {
  let save = {
    ashCount: ashCount,
    firetruck: firetruck
  }
  localStorage.setItem("save", JSON.stringify(save));
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Well, looking at your code, you just get the value from `localStorage` and set it to variable `sg`, then you do nothing with this variable that can update something

Comment: Im not doing anything with it right now, im saying upon returning to the webpage localstorage returns ashCount = 0 even though upon leaving webpage value was stored at say 23, even If i wanted to do something, the value isnt saved when revisiting site

Comment: so, are you saying after the `let sg = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("save"));` (before setting the new sg.ashCount), if you log `sg` you get an object where `ashCount` is 0? to be honest, I think you are probably setting it to zero here: `sg.ashCount = ashCount;`

Comment: Rick pointed that out aswell, im terrible thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you wrote `sg.ashCount = ashCount;` when you want `ashCount = sg.ashCount;`

add a console.log(sg);